# How do I fix a Net.stream iOS crash

Tags: ios, crash, video-streaming

I am a teacher who has developed an app that streams video tutorials to mobile devices. The app has been around for a while and was originally built in CS6 using AIR SDK 20. More recently I have moved to CC and published the app using CC and AIR SDK 23 and 24 (including beta 24.0.180).

The app now crashes on IOS first access after installing the app. When you open the app up again, it opens but will crash when pulling up the control centre, pulling down the notification bar, clicking on the home button or minimising the app with a pinch.

I have stripped out the code and have isolated the problem to video streaming within the project. The issue is replicated using the xml and swf file found here: Dropbox - 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h4rht8ksps2k1gg/AADdlFLst5CALJgl6oUsziIUa?dl=0 
(everything has been stripped from the project so I appreciate that no video will play - didn't need it to play to replicate the issue). The app has been installed on iPad Air with IOS10 and iPad Mini 1 IOS9, but my students have also experienced the issue on iPhones running IOS7 +.

Any help with this would be much appreciated as my students would like to use the app without the issues.

Kind regards
Matt